# SynchronizationLockException on Monitor.Exit when using await

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am creating a piece of code that gets a webpage from a legacy system we have. In order to avoid excessive querying, I am caching the obtained URL. I am using `Monitor.Enter`, `Monitor.Exit` and double checking to avoid that request is issued twice, but when releasing the lock with `Monitor.Exit`, I am getting this exception:

```
System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException was caught
  HResult=-2146233064
  Message=Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
  Source=MyApp
  StackTrace:
       at MyApp.Data.ExProvider.<OpenFeature>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\Data\ExProvider.cs:line 56
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at MyApp.Data.ExProvider.<GetSupportFor>d__15.MoveNext() in c:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\Data\ExProvider.cs:line 71
  InnerException:
```

The line 56 is the `Monitor.Exit`. This is the code that performs the operation:

```
private async Task<Stream> OpenReport(String report)
{
    var file = _directory.GetFiles(report+ ".html");
    if (file != null && file.Any())
        return file[0].OpenRead();
    else
    {
        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(_locker);
            FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(_directory.FullName, report + ".html"));
            if (!newFile.Exists) // Double check
            {
                using (var target = newFile.OpenWrite())
                {
                    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(BuildUrl(report));
                    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                    using (var source = response.GetResponseStream())
                        source.CopyTo(target);
                }
            }
            return newFile.OpenRead();
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_locker);
        }
    }
}
```

So what is the problem with `await` and `Monitor`? Is it because it is not the same thread when `Monitor.Enter` than when `Monitor.Exit`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can't `await` a task inside a `lock` scope (which is syntactic sugar for `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`). Using a `Monitor` directly will fool the compiler but not the framework.

`async-await` has no thread-affinity like a `Monitor` does. The code after the `await` will probably run in a different thread than the code before it. Which means that the thread that releases the `Monitor` isn't necessarily the one that acquired it.

Either don't use `async-await` in this case, or use a different synchronization construct like `SemaphoreSlim` or an `AsyncLock` you can build yourself. Here's mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21011273/885318

Comment: Should it be ok with a ManualResetEventSlim?

Comment: It can be, but it's much easier with a SemaphoreSlim set to 1, because you can await it and it isn't thread-affine

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I'm not getting any exception in following code block when I was expecting SynchronizationLockException.Not sure why it is not throwing exception as per known behavior of await and lock.`static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsyncFunctionWithLock();
        }

        private static async void AsyncFunctionWithLock()
        {
            Monitor.Enter(lockObject);
            {
                await AsyncFunctionWithLock2();
            }
            Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
        }

        private static async Task AsyncFunctionWithLock2()
        {
           
        }`

Comment: @RasikBihariTiwari `AsyncFunctionWithLock2` isn't actually asynchronous. It doesn't await anything so it continues on synchronously on the same thread.

Comment: @i3arnon appreciate ur quick response.I was finally able to get that exception with this change in my function:`private static async Task AsyncFunctionWithLock3()
{    //simulate long running taks so task scheduler schedules it
//on a threadpool thread instead of the main UI thread itself.
 string filename = @"C:\temp.txt";
            byte[] result;
            using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                result = new byte[SourceStream.Length];
                await SourceStream.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)SourceStream.Length); }}}`

Answer (score 10):

> In SendRequest however, I need to 'await', and thus I'm unable to use lock for some reason I didn't give much thought, so the solution to synchronize is to use Monitor.

Should have given it more thought. :)

There are two problems with using blocking locks with `async` code.

The first problem is that - in the general case - an `async` method may resume executing on a different thread. Most blocking locks are thread-affine, meaning that they must be released from the thread that *owns* them (the same thread that acquired the lock). It is this violation of `Monitor` thread-affinity that causes the `SynchronizationLockException`. This problem does not happen if the `await` captures an execution context (e.g., a UI context) and used that to resume the `async` method (e.g., on the UI thread). Or if you just got lucky and the `async` method *happened* to resume on the same thread pool thread.

However, even if you avoid the first problem, you still have a second problem: any arbitrary code can execute while an `async` method is "paused" at an `await` point. This is a violation of a cardinal rule of locking ("do not execute arbitrary code while holding a lock"). For example, thread-affine locks (including `Monitor`) are generally re-entrant, so even in the UI thread scenario, when your `async` method is "paused" (and holding the lock), other methods running on the UI thread can take the lock without any problems.

On Windows Phone 8, use `SemaphoreSlim` instead. This is a type that allows both blocking and asynchronous coordination. Use `Wait` for a blocking lock and `WaitAsync` for an asynchronous lock.

Comment: FYI: answer merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368917/c-sharp-synchronizationlockexception-on-monitor-exit-when-async-method-called-fr

Comment: @Stephen Cleary, I have purchased your book on concurrency and is still on my "to-read" list. Does your book cover the above scenarios as well?

Comment: @wenn32: I do cover asynchronous locks but I don't remember if I go into detail with the regular lock in asynchronous code or not.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary, maybe for the third edition ;)
Anyways, thanks a lot for the great book. Hoping to get some time to finish it soon. Excited to read. Take care.