# Exception "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code." in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am loading up some values from my database to be displayed to my website users. Since these values won't be changing too much, I am loading them up into a static/shared object.

To ensure that multiple users aren't modifying this same object at the same time, I am using `Monitor.Enter` (and `Monitor.Exit`) to lock/block around the loading of these values.

Unfortunately, this does not work when being called from an MVC view in .NET as it throws this exception:

> Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.

Is there a way to do this, via MVC, without completely changing my code design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You see this error because you, most probably, use Monitor inside of async method. But you should not, can read more about this issue here [monitor in async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404144/synchronizationlockexception-on-monitor-exit-when-using-await)

You can simply replace Monitor with [SemaphoreSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) or [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)